# Label VBA code with line numbers

Tags: vba

Is there a way to quickly label VBA code with line numbers such as shown below?

```
Sub sample()

     Dim i As Long

10   Debug.Print "A"
20   Debug.Print "B"
30   Debug.Print "C"
40   Debug.Print "D"    
50   MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: Why? what is the end reason?

Comment: @ScottCraner, motivated from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398261/how-to-check-which-line-of-vba-code-is-causing-errors). I don't fully develop my code because its for internal use only, and my users hardly feed back when they get errors. Hence I've able to obtain statistics on when they get errors, what error (`err.description`) and which procedure, but I need to know on which line of the code. I can certainly label them manually now, but would like to know an easier way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this answer [Log what line error occurs: vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809960/log-what-line-error-occurs-vba), there are two ways to do that:

1. Either manually (not fast, so doesn't answer your question)
2. Or with some add-in, like the one mentioned in the linked answer
3. Or write your own add-in using `VBA Extensibility` to do that.

**Edit:** I never worked with `VBE extensivbility` library so I would suggest consulting other sources, for example here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
Repurposing code written by Chip Pearson I would try the following, although this I haven't tested it:

```
    With VBComp.CodeModule 'VBComp is VBIDE.VBComponent
        For N = 1 To .CountOfLines
            If Trim(.Lines(N, 1)) = vbNullString Then
                ' blank line, skip it
            ElseIf Left(Trim(.Lines(N, 1)), 1) = "'" Then
                ' comment line, skip it
            Else
                .Lines(N, 1) = N & " " & .Lines(N,1)
            End If
        Next N
    End With
```

Keep in mind, that you need to make sure that you check for various cases, for example for the lines that are already numbered.

Comment: can you explain where to begin using VBA extensibility ? Tks.

Comment: thanks.. appreciate your time, i'll test it out later

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide all the modules in your workbook with (updated) line numbers (adding and removing) you can apply the steps below*^°°. Please take this warning into account.

**Do Once:**

1. Paste the large code from  `Module2` in your workbook.
2. Paste the code for  `Module3`  in your workbook.
3. Paste the code for  `Module4`  in your workbook.
4. Then paste the line `Global allow_for_line_addition As String`this is just so that you can automatically add linenumbers` above/in the first line of every
   module.
5. Delete all empty lines at the end of each module (so no lose enters after the last `end sub`,`end function` or `End Property` of a module).
6. In the VBA editor, while not running a code, and not being in "break"-mode:click tools>references>mark: `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"

**Do every time you have modified your code:**

7. °Run the code for  `Module3` to remove line numbers to all the modules in your workbook.
8. °Run the code for  `Module4` to add line numbers to all the modules in your workbook.

**`Module2`**:

```
    Public Enum vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes
        vbLabelColon    ' 0
        vbLabelTab      ' 1
    End Enum

    Public Enum vbLineNumbers_ScopeToAddLineNumbersTo
        vbScopeAllProc  ' 1
        vbScopeThisProc ' 2
    End Enum
              Sub AddLineNumbers(ByVal wbName As String, _
                                                          ByVal vbCompName As String, _
                                                          ByVal LabelType As vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes, _
                                                          ByVal AddLineNumbersToEmptyLines As Boolean, _
                                                          ByVal AddLineNumbersToEndOfProc As Boolean, _
                                                          ByVal Scope As vbLineNumbers_ScopeToAddLineNumbersTo, _
                                                          Optional ByVal thisProcName As String)

    ' USAGE RULES
    ' DO NOT MIX LABEL TYPES FOR LINE NUMBERS! IF ADDING LINE NUMBERS AS COLON TYPE, ANY LINE NUMBERS AS VBTAB TYPE MUST BE REMOVE BEFORE, AND RECIPROCALLY ADDING LINE NUMBERS AS VBTAB TYPE

        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim procName As String
        Dim startOfProcedure As Long
        Dim lengthOfProcedure As Long
        Dim endOfProcedure As Long
        Dim strLine As String

        With Workbooks(wbName).VBProject.VBComponents(vbCompName).CodeModule
            .CodePane.Window.Visible = False

    If Scope = vbScopeAllProc Then

            For i = 1 To .CountOfLines - 1

                strLine = .Lines(i, 1)
                procName = .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc) ' Type d'argument ByRef incompatible ~~> Requires VBIDE library as a Reference for the VBA Project

                If procName <> vbNullString Then
                    startOfProcedure = .ProcStartLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
                    bodyOfProcedure = .ProcBodyLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
                    countOfProcedure = .ProcCountLines(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)

                    prelinesOfProcedure = bodyOfProcedure - startOfProcedure
                    'postlineOfProcedure = ??? not directly available since endOfProcedure is itself not directly available.

                    lengthOfProcedure = countOfProcedure - prelinesOfProcedure ' includes postlinesOfProcedure !
                    'endOfProcedure = ??? not directly available, each line of the proc must be tested until the End statement is reached. See below.

                    If endOfProcedure <> 0 And startOfProcedure < endOfProcedure And i > endOfProcedure Then
                        GoTo NextLine
                    End If

                    If i = bodyOfProcedure Then inprocbodylines = True

                    If bodyOfProcedure < i And i < startOfProcedure + countOfProcedure Then
                        If Not (.Lines(i - 1, 1) Like "* _") Then

                            inprocbodylines = False

                            PreviousIndentAdded = 0

                            If Trim(strLine) = "" And Not AddLineNumbersToEmptyLines Then GoTo NextLine

                            If IsProcEndLine(wbName, vbCompName, i) Then
                                endOfProcedure = i
                                If AddLineNumbersToEndOfProc Then
                                    Call IndentProcBodyLinesAsProcEndLine(wbName, vbCompName, LabelType, endOfProcedure)
                                Else
                                    GoTo NextLine
                                End If
                            End If

                            If LabelType = vbLabelColon Then
                                If HasLabel(strLine, vbLabelColon) Then strLine = RemoveOneLineNumber(.Lines(i, 1), vbLabelColon)
                                If Not HasLabel(strLine, vbLabelColon) Then
                                    temp_strLine = strLine
                                    .ReplaceLine i, CStr(i) & ":" & strLine
                                    new_strLine = .Lines(i, 1)
                                    If Len(new_strLine) = Len(CStr(i) & ":" & temp_strLine) Then
                                        PreviousIndentAdded = Len(CStr(i) & ":")
                                    Else
                                        PreviousIndentAdded = Len(CStr(i) & ": ")
                                    End If
                                End If
                            ElseIf LabelType = vbLabelTab Then
                                If Not HasLabel(strLine, vbLabelTab) Then strLine = RemoveOneLineNumber(.Lines(i, 1), vbLabelTab)
                                If Not HasLabel(strLine, vbLabelColon) Then
                                    temp_strLine = strLine
                                    .ReplaceLine i, CStr(i) & vbTab & strLine
                                    PreviousIndentAdded = Len(strLine) - Len(temp_strLine)
                                End If
                            End If

                        Else
                            If Not inprocbodylines Then
                                If LabelType = vbLabelColon Then
                                    .ReplaceLine i, Space(PreviousIndentAdded) & strLine
                                ElseIf LabelType = vbLabelTab Then
                                    .ReplaceLine i, Space(4) & strLine
                                End If
                            Else
                            End If
                        End If

                    End If

                End If

    NextLine:
            Next i

    ElseIf AddLineNumbersToEmptyLines And Scope = vbScopeThisProc Then

    End If

            .CodePane.Window.Visible = True
        End With

    End Sub
              Function IsProcEndLine(ByVal wbName As String, _
                  ByVal vbCompName As String, _
                  ByVal Line As Long) As Boolean

    With Workbooks(wbName).VBProject.VBComponents(vbCompName).CodeModule
    If Trim(.Lines(Line, 1)) Like "End Sub*" _
                Or Trim(.Lines(Line, 1)) Like "End Function*" _
                Or Trim(.Lines(Line, 1)) Like "End Property*" _
                Then IsProcEndLine = True
    End With

    End Function
              Sub IndentProcBodyLinesAsProcEndLine(ByVal wbName As String, ByVal vbCompName As String, ByVal LabelType As vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes, ByVal ProcEndLine As Long)
        Dim procName As String
        Dim startOfProcedure As Long
        Dim endOfProcedure As Long

        With Workbooks(wbName).VBProject.VBComponents(vbCompName).CodeModule

            procName = .ProcOfLine(ProcEndLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
            bodyOfProcedure = .ProcBodyLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
            endOfProcedure = ProcEndLine
            strEnd = .Lines(endOfProcedure, 1)

            j = bodyOfProcedure
            Do Until Not .Lines(j - 1, 1) Like "* _" And j <> bodyOfProcedure

                strLine = .Lines(j, 1)

                If LabelType = vbLabelColon Then
                    If Mid(strEnd, Len(CStr(endOfProcedure)) + 1 + 1 + 1, 1) = " " Then
                        .ReplaceLine j, Space(Len(CStr(endOfProcedure)) + 1) & strLine
                    Else
                        .ReplaceLine j, Space(Len(CStr(endOfProcedure)) + 2) & strLine
                    End If
                ElseIf LabelType = vbLabelTab Then
                    If endOfProcedure < 1000 Then
                        .ReplaceLine j, Space(4) & strLine
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "This tool is limited to 999 lines of code to work properly."
                    End If
                End If

                j = j + 1
            Loop

        End With
    End Sub
              Sub RemoveLineNumbers(ByVal wbName As String, ByVal vbCompName As String, ByVal LabelType As vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes)
        Dim i As Long
        With Workbooks(wbName).VBProject.VBComponents(vbCompName).CodeModule
            'MsgBox ("nr of lines = " & .CountOfLines & vbNewLine & "Procname = " & procName)
                'MsgBox ("nr of lines REMEMBER MUST BE LARGER THAN 7! = " & .CountOfLines)
            For i = 1 To .CountOfLines
                procName = .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc)
                If procName <> vbNullString Then
                    If i > 1 Then
                            'MsgBox ("Line " & i & " is a body line " & .ProcBodyLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc))
                        If i = .ProcBodyLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc) Then inprocbodylines = True
                            If .Lines(i - 1, 1) <> "" Then
                                'MsgBox (.Lines(i - 1, 1))
                            End If
                        If Not .Lines(i - 1, 1) Like "* _" Then
                            'MsgBox (inprocbodylines)
                            inprocbodylines = False
                                'MsgBox ("recoginized a line that should be substituted: " & i)
                            'MsgBox ("about to replace " & .Lines(i, 1) & vbNewLine & " with: " & RemoveOneLineNumber(.Lines(i, 1), LabelType) & vbNewLine & " with label type: " & LabelType)
                            .ReplaceLine i, RemoveOneLineNumber(.Lines(i, 1), LabelType)
                        Else
                            If IsInProcBodyLines Then
                                ' do nothing
                                    'MsgBox (i)
                            Else
                                .ReplaceLine i, Mid(.Lines(i, 1), RemovedChars_previous_i + 1)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                ' GoTo NextLine
                End If
    NextLine:
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub
              Function RemoveOneLineNumber(ByVal aString As String, ByVal LabelType As vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes)
        RemoveOneLineNumber = aString
        If LabelType = vbLabelColon Then
            If aString Like "#:*" Or aString Like "##:*" Or aString Like "###:*" Or aString Like "####:*" Then
                RemoveOneLineNumber = Mid(aString, 1 + InStr(1, aString, ":", vbTextCompare))
                If Left(RemoveOneLineNumber, 2) Like " [! ]*" Then RemoveOneLineNumber = Mid(RemoveOneLineNumber, 2)
            End If
        ElseIf LabelType = vbLabelTab Then
            If aString Like "#   *" Or aString Like "##  *" Or aString Like "### *" Or aString Like "#### *" Then RemoveOneLineNumber = Mid(aString, 5)
            If aString Like "#" Or aString Like "##" Or aString Like "###" Or aString Like "####" Then RemoveOneLineNumber = ""
        End If
    End Function
              Function HasLabel(ByVal aString As String, ByVal LabelType As vbLineNumbers_LabelTypes) As Boolean
        If LabelType = vbLabelColon Then HasLabel = InStr(1, aString & ":", ":") < InStr(1, aString & " ", " ")
        If LabelType = vbLabelTab Then
            HasLabel = Mid(aString, 1, 4) Like "#   " Or Mid(aString, 1, 4) Like "##  " Or Mid(aString, 1, 4) Like "### " Or Mid(aString, 1, 5) Like "#### "
        End If
    End Function
              Function RemoveLeadingSpaces(ByVal aString As String) As String
        Do Until Left(aString, 1) <> " "
            aString = Mid(aString, 2)
        Loop
        RemoveLeadingSpaces = aString
    End Function
              Function WhatIsLineIndent(ByVal aString As String) As String
        i = 1
        Do Until Mid(aString, i, 1) <> " "
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        WhatIsLineIndent = i
    End Function

              Function HowManyLeadingSpaces(ByVal aString As String) As String
        HowManyLeadingSpaces = WhatIsLineIndent(aString) - 1
    End Function
```

**`Module3`**:

```
    Global allow_for_line_addition As String 'this is just so that you can automatically add linenumbers
            Sub remove_line_numbering_all_modules()
    'source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791473/vba-getting-the-modules-in-workbook
    'This code numbers all the modules in your .xlsm
        Dim vbcomp As VBComponent
        Dim modules As Collection
    Set modules = New Collection
        For Each vbcomp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
            'if normal or class module
            If ((vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule) Or (vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule)) Then
                   'V0:
                   RemoveLineNumbers wbName:=ThisWorkbook.name, vbCompName:=vbcomp.name, LabelType:=vbLabelColon
                   'V1:
                   'Call RemoveLineNumbers(ThisWorkbook.name, vbcomp.name)
            End If
        Next vbcomp
    End Sub
```

**`Module4`**:

```
    Global allow_for_line_addition As String 'this is just so that you can automatically add linenumbers
    'This sub adds line numbers to all the modules after you have added the following line to every module
    'add tools references microsoft visual basic for applications (5.3) as checked
    'Source httpsstackoverflow.comquestions40731182excel-vba-how-to-turn-on-line-numbers-in-code-editor50368332#50368332
            Sub add_line_numbering_all_modules()
    'source: https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/36791473/vba-getting-the-modules-in-workbook
    'This code numbers all the modules in your .xlsm
        Dim vbcomp As VBComponent
        Dim modules As Collection
        Set modules = New Collection
        For Each vbcomp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
            'if normal or class module
            If ((vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule) Or (vbcomp.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule)) Then
                   'V0:
                   Call AddLineNumbers(ThisWorkbook.name, vbcomp.name, vbLabelColon, True, True, vbScopeAllProc)
                   'v1
                   'Call AddLineNumbers(ThisWorkbook.name, vbcomp.name)
            End If
        Next vbcomp
    End Sub
```

where you can either substitute `"Book1.xlsm"` with the name of your own workbook, or with `thisworkbook` (notice no ""), or vice versa.

- *Note this worked in excel 2016, I have not tried it in 2013 yet.
- ^It is a modified version of Hemced's answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731182/excel-vba-how-to-turn-on-line-numbers-in-code-editor/50368332#50368332), which in turn, looks a lot like Arich's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459541/adding-line-numbers-to-vba-code-microsoft-access-2016/50394349#50394349).
- °because sometimes you get an error if you cut lines out or move them around (e.g. put `line 2440:` above `line 2303:`). By removing and re-adding them, the line numbering is automatically correct again.
- °°Tested in Excel 2016.